# sql compact 3.5, select top n rows from each group

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I am writing a query to select the top 1 record from each group. Keep in mind that I working on sql compact 3.5 and thus can not use the rank function. I'm pretty sure my query is incorrect but I'm not sure how to select top from each group. Any one got any ideas?

Here is the query I was trying to get working

/*
 * added fH.InvoiceNumber to my query to get result further below.
 */
    select tH.*, t.CustomerNumber, c.CustomerName, fH.Status, fH.InvoiceNumber
    from tenderHeader tH
    join task t ON tH.TaskActivityID = t.ActivityID
    join finalizeTicketHeader fH ON tH.FinalizeTicketTaskActivityID = fH.TaskActivityID
    join customer c ON t.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber
    where fH.Status <> '3' AND t.TripID = '08ea6982-6efd-46fa-9753-0fd8b076f24c';

Here is what my tables look like:

```
customer table:

|------------------------------------------------|
| CustomerNumber | CustomerName | Address1 | ... |
|------------------------------------------------|
| 0012084737     | Customer A   | 150 Rd A | ... |
|------------------------------------------------|
| 0012301891     | Customer B   | 152 Rd A | ... |
|------------------------------------------------|

task table

|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| ActivityID | TripID    | TaskTypeName | Status | CustomerNumber | 
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| 4967f6cc   | 08ea6982  | Payment      | 2      | 0012084737     |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| e96469a1   | 08ea6982  | Payment      | 2      | 0012301891     |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|

finalizeTicketHeader table

|---------------------------------------------------|
| TaskActivityID | InvoiceNumber | Amount  | Status |
|---------------------------------------------------|
| 916082c8       | 1000          | 563.32  | 3      |
|---------------------------------------------------|
| 916082c8       | 1001          | -343.68 | 0      |
|---------------------------------------------------|
| 4b38bf60       | 1002          | 152.29  | 0      |
|---------------------------------------------------|
| 4b38bf60       | 1003          | -35.80  | 0      |
|---------------------------------------------------|

tenderHeader table

|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| TaskActivityID | InvoiceNumber | PastDue | TodaysDue | FinalizeTicketTaskActivityID |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 4967f6cc       | 1234567891    | 23.55   | 219.64    | 916082c8                     |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| e96469a1       | 1234567893    | 0.00    | 116.49    | 4b38bf60                     |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

the problem I was having was getting duplicates.

like so:

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| TaskActivityID | InvoiceNumber | PastDue | TodaysDue | FinalizeTicketTaskActivityID | CustomerNumber | CustomerName | InvoiceNumber |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 4967f6cc       | 1234567891    | 23.55   | 219.64    | 916082c8                     | 0012084737     | Customer A   | 1001         |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| e96469a1       | 1234567893    | 0.00    | 116.49    | 4b38bf60                     | 0012301891     | Customer B   | 1002         |              
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| e96469a1       | 1234567893    | 0.00    | 116.49    | 4b38bf60                     | 0012301891     | Customer B   | 1003         |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I've rewritten the query like so, but I need to get specific columns from the sub query.

```
select tH.* from tenderHeader th
inner join task t on tH.TaskActivityID = t.ActivityID
inner join (
    select k.TaskActivityID from finalizeTicketHeader k group by k.TaskActivityID
) as fH on tH.FinalizeTicketTaskActivityID = fH.TaskActivityID
inner join customer c on t.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber
```

I need to get the status from fH. Any ideas of how to do that?

```
select tH.*, fH.Status from tenderHeader th
inner join task t on tH.TaskActivityID = t.ActivityID
inner join finalizeTicketHeader fH on tH.FinalizeTicketTaskActivityID = tH.TaskActivityID
inner join customer c on t.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber
where tH.FinalizeTicketTaskActivityID = (
    select top (1) k.TaskActivityID from finalizeTicketHeader k 
);
```

but it seems that sql compact 3.5 does not support scalar values with subquery in where cause.

Comment: What columns do you use to create groups?

Comment: I almost had this working by using a subquery in the where cause for an equals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that demonstrat a way of selecting the top 1 from each group

```
id|time
--------
2 | 1:10
2 | 0:45 
2 | 1:45
2 | 1:30
1 | 1:00
1 | 1:10
```

the table is called table_1; we group by id and assume that time should be desc ordered

```
 select table_1.* from table_1
 inner join (
     select id, max(time) as max_time from table_1
     group by id
 ) as t
 on t.max_time = table_1.time and table_1.id = t.id
 order by table_1.id
```

the result we get is

```
id|time
--------
1 | 1:10
2 | 1:45
```